# Appending multiple xml files to a single output using xsl-fo

Tags: java, xml, xsl-fo, postscript

I'm creating a PostScript file from XML input using xsl-fo (Apache-FOP).
I need also to append multiple such XML to a single PS file.
1. Does Apache-FOP support appending to output? 
2. if not, is there away around this issue? (concatenating the XMLs is not an option).

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/Xsl/func_document.asp perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

merging multiple PDF files (I guess it should work with ps too (sDEVICE=pswrite ?) ):

```
gs -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOUTPUTFILE=merged.pdf -dBATCH *.pdf
```